# Return a value after doing a post with AJAX to use that value in other code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So, as You can see in the code bellow I want to do a "if" statement to check if the query had correctly ran. If yes, it stores in a var, `$output`, a part of a script, and for what? To immediately be read by the rest of the notification script that is included in the ajax script.

Basically the "if" statement its only used to format the notification type, like success, error etc.

I'm using the overhang.js as notification.

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'teste');
if(!$con) {
  die('Connection not Establish');
}

if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
  $output='';
  $texto=$_POST['texto'];
  $data_nasc=$_POST['data'];
  $sql="INSERT INTO teste(texto, data) VALUES ('$texto', '$data_nasc')";
  $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  if($result) {
    $buscar=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM teste ORDER BY id DESC");
    $linha=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar);
    $output ='$("body").overhang({
      type: "success",
      message: "Yeiii",
      closeConfirm: true
    });';
 echo $output;
  }
  else {
    $output.='$("body").overhang({
      type: "error",
      message: "Whoops! Something went wrong!",
      closeConfirm: true
    });';
 echo $output;
  }
}

?>
```

`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','teste');
if(!$con)
{
   die('Connection not Establish');
}
$sql="SELECT * from teste";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
  <!Doctype html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>How to show data on bootstrap modal using ajax with php</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Paul Krishnamurthy" />
    <link rel="icon" href="demo/logo.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/style/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/overhang.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/style/prism.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/overhang.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/prism.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/index.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 align="center">How to show data on bootstrap modal using ajax with php</h1>
      <button style="margin-top:10%;" class="submit" id="">Click to show data on bootstrap modal</button>
      <input type="text" name="texto">
      <input type="date" name="data_nasc">

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.submit', function() {
          $texto = $("input[name=texto]").val();
          $data = $("input[name=data_nasc]").val();

          $.ajax({
            url: "show_data.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {
              texto: $texto,
              data: $data
            },
            success: function(data) {

              <?php echo $output;?>
            }
          });
        });
      </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Instead of writing Javascript with php why not let php do it's server side magic and just return true or false. And then in Javascript write the javascript code and decide which alert to show? The problem is that the text return from php is treated as text and it is not really executed as javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only return true or false from server side code using ajax
and handle the rest of javascript inside ajax success method.

Server side code:

```
<?php 
  $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'teste');
  if(!$con) {
    die('Connection not Establish');
  }

  if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $output='';
    $texto=$_POST['texto'];
    $data_nasc=$_POST['data'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO teste(texto, data) VALUES ('$texto', '$data_nasc')";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if($result) {
      $buscar=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM teste ORDER BY id DESC");
      $linha=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar);
      $output = TRUE;
  }
  else {
      $output = FALSE;
  }
  echo $output;

  }

?>
```

Client side code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','teste');
if(!$con)
{
  die('Connection not Establish');
}
$sql="SELECT * from teste";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>How to show data on bootstrap modal using ajax with php</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="author" content="Paul Krishnamurthy" />
  <link rel="icon" href="demo/logo.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/style/index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/overhang.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/style/prism.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/overhang.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/prism.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">How to show data on bootstrap modal using ajax with php</h1>
    <button style="margin-top:10%;" class="submit" id="">Click to show data on bootstrap modal</button>
    <input type="text" name="texto">
    <input type="date" name="data_nasc">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('click', '.submit', function() {
        $texto = $("input[name=texto]").val();
        $data = $("input[name=data_nasc]").val();

        $.ajax({
          url: "show_data.php",
          method: "post",
          data: {
            texto: $texto,
            data: $data
          },
          success: function(data) {

            if(data == true){
              // success 
              $("body").overhang({
                type: "success",
                message: "Yeiii",
                closeConfirm: true
              });

            }else{
              // your false script 2019-07-08 11:10:33
              $("body").overhang({
                type: "error",
                message: "Whoops! Something went wrong!",
                closeConfirm: true
              });
            }
            <?php echo $output;?>
          }
        });
      });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mysqli_error()` method to check if the query has errors.
In your current code, I suggest using JSON as the return type in your **PHP** side. To extract data in js use `JSON.parse(data)`. I do not recommend using `<?php echo $output;?>` in the js.

```
if (mysqli_error($buscar))
{
   // an error eoccurred
}
```